# Fade in enter (from right to center) and leave (from center to left)

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I have a text that is centered. it's replaced every 4 seconds.
I want that when a text is displayed: it will come from the right (opacity=0) to the center (opacity=1),
and when the text is hidden, it will go from the center (opacity=1) to the left (opacity=0).

This is what I tried:

```
.fade.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s ease-out all;
  opacity:0;
}

.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}

.fade.ng-leave {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:1;
}
.fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
```

This is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwNomv

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You don't have dependency on ng-animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have dependency on `ng-animate`. And even if you did, it won't work, because `ng-animate` supports directives like `ng-view`, `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `ng-repeat`.

What you are doing is simply changing the visible text. You need to make use of either of these directives to make ng-animate work.

Instead, if you want it to work, you will have to add these classes yourself, and it can be done using JQlite API, you can make use of `addClass()`, `removeClass()` and `toggleClass()`.

```
var element = angular.element( 'id' );

/** Use timeouts to clearly decide when an element at which state. */
element.addClass( 'ng-enter' );
```

An another solution using KeyFrames has been implemented [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwNoYQ).

Answer (score -1):

You should use webkit animation. you can find more info at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp